# Trying to get testcafe, saucelabs and circleci working together but having no luck

Tags: automated-tests, circleci, saucelabs, testcafe, circleci-2.0

So I have the following in my package.json:

test-sl-one: "testcafe \"saucelabs:Chrome@beta:Windows 10\" tests/settings/users.js -r xunit:/tmp/test-results/res.xml"

I see the tunnel "active" on the saucelabs site.

I wait about four minutes, and then I get back the error:

> testcafe-automated-tests@0.0.1 test-sl-one /home/circleci/repo
>   testcafe "saucelabs:Chrome@beta:Windows 10" tests/settings/users.js -r xunit:/tmp/test-results/res.xml

ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.

Any advice on where to start to triage it etc would be greatly appreciated! :)

Details:  I successfully run testcafe tests on circleci not using saucelabs (just using a docker image that has chrome/firefox in it).
Also, my tests are running inside a docker container (maybe I should stop doing this part)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestCafe, CircleCI 2.0 & SauceLabs -- can't get this combination to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653378/testcafe-circleci-2-0-saucelabs-cant-get-this-combination-to-work)

Comment: Could you please share an example which I can on my side?